# Bigger than stops on invalid number

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a variable set like this: `x = 1;` and I have made an interval which every 100 milliseconds adds to the `x` + `0.1`, inside the Interval I have a `if` which checks for if `x` is bigger than something. So I was testing around and I saw that `IF` was called on a wrong time.

Code:

```
if(Math.pow(1.06, 18.90).toFixed(2) >= 24.91){
    clearInterval(timer);
}
```

As you can see, `X` was 18.90, but if using the math function it equals to 3.01 how can that be bigger than 24.91?

Comment: `toFixed` returns a string, not a number, and so the comparision is a string comparison (alphabetical). Solution: don't use `toFixed`, or cast the result back to number with the unary `+`.

Comment: I don't know, when I run it in the console, I get `Math.pow(1.06, 18.90).toFixed(2) >= 24.91 >>> false` You're saying your application test returns true here and executes the `clearInterval()`? Can you add a fiddle?

Comment: @trincot - How is alphabetical `"3.01"` greater than `24.91`?

Comment: Ahh yeah, my bad. Forgot that toFixed returns a string.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, true, it would be smaller. I assume that the OP simplified their question, but that in reality they are comparing strings. Otherwise this issue is not reproducible.

Comment: @trincot Or the OP is mistaken?